# Is this question asked on scifi.stackexchange.com on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have asked [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38394/energy-consumption-for-travelling-to-the-moon-vs-to-mars) on scifi.stackexchange.com. Someone suggested I instead ask the question over here on Space Exploration to get better answers. Would that question be accepted here at all?

Note that I don't actually intend to cross-post *this* question (unless you want me to), but if the answer is positive I might ask a few other questions that are rooted in Science Fiction.

Comment: Please note, that while the question you posted on SciFi is perfectly on topic for SEx.SE, your other questions (that you intend to ask) may or may be not. Anything about trajectory design is on-topic here, though.

Comment: *cross-post* a 2nd time? Where else was it posted?

Comment: @Tshepang Just my incorrect usage of the word "cross-post".

Comment: Can you fix it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out the references to the sci-fi book and I think you are perfectly ok.

By the way, the answer is a definite maybe.  It's not clear from the question if you are or are not including ascents/descents from the planetary surfaces.  Also, if you use aerobraking at Mars, you gain a huge advantage that you can't use when going to the moon.

Answer (score 4):

When I answered it, I thought it was here, because I wasn't really paying attention. I agree, this site is a better fit, and I've moved it over here.

The science fiction references are okay, but the tags will need to be changed, but I've done that for now, feel free to change if required.

Comment: I will leave the question as it is because editing it too much would make the answers and comments hard to understand. Thanks for the move, btw.